# How to disable TLS 1.0 on a single Virtual Host in LBL ADC (version without GUI)

Tags: tls1.0

I need to disable the TLS 1.0 on a single virtual host, the version of LBL is older (Version 9).
How can i do it?

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 1):

In a OPLON LBL Application Delivery Controller you can enable and disable SSL/TLS Protocols and cipher suite for all listeners or for a single listener.

Below the parameters for the single listener.
If set, the parameters of the individual listeners override the general parameters.

**Parameter: SSLProtocols="TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"**

```
        <bind enable="true"
              description="Sample HTTPS listener"
              listenType="NAT"
              address="192.168.56.17 192.168.178.70"
              port="443"
              SSL="true"
              SSLSNI="false"
              SSLSNIDefaultCertificateEnable="false"
              SSLContextVersion="SSLv3"
              SSLUseCipherSuitesOrder="true"
              aliasPassword="defaultpwd"
              certificateURIPath="serverkeys"
              certificateURL=""
              checkClientCertificateValidity="false"
              SSLProtocols="TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"
              cipherSuites="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA256 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA"
              enableVirtualDomain="true"
              endPointsGrouping="http_https"
              forwardClientCertificateChainDepth="1"
              forwardClientCertificateToEndpoint="false"
              forwardClientPemCertificateToEndpoint="false"
              keyStore="JKS"
              keyManagerFactory="SunX509"
              keyStorePassword="defaultpwd"
              needClientAuthentication="true"
              osiLayer="7"
              portForwarding="false"
              sslSessionCacheSize="0"
              sslSessionCacheTimeout="86400"
              transport="tcp"
              trustAllCertificates="true"
              trustCertificateURIPath="trustStore.jks"
              trustKeyStore="JKS"
              trustKeyStorePassword="test"
              xForwardedFor="true"/>
```

And on this paragraph the parameters for all the listeners:

**Parameter: SSLProtocolsListeners="TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"**

```
    <params 
            SSLProtocolsListeners="TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"
            cipherSuitesListeners="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA256 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA"
            clientH2Bridge="false"
            clientSSLUseCipherSuitesOrder="true"
            concurrentSessions="-1"
            dosAttackPrevention="false"
            dosAttackPreventionOnlyClose="false"
            endPointSSLUseCipherSuitesOrder="true"
            maxConcurrentSessions="-1">
    </params>
```